# create and modify xml file using javascript (want to save xml file on client side)

Tags: javascript, xml

How to save xml file on client side using javascript...?

```
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else // Internet Explorer 5/6
        {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "User.xml", false);
        xhttp.send("");
        xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

        xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Username")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'asdasf';
        xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("password")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'asdAS';
        xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("UserId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = '12';
        xmlDoc.save("User.xml");
```

this is not working.. showing error as save is not a function.

Thanks
Suneetha.

Comment: If you can explain the scenario then it would be much more helpful in finding out an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is not allowed in JavaScript. This will be a security vulnerability.

Read [JavaScript security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security)

> JavaScript and the DOM provide the
>   potential for malicious authors to
>   deliver scripts to run on a client
>   computer via the web. Browser authors
>   contain this risk using two
>   restrictions. First, scripts run in a
>   sandbox in which they can only perform
>   web-related actions, not
>   general-purpose programming tasks like
>   creating files. Second, scripts are
>   constrained by the same origin policy:
>   scripts from one web site do not have
>   access to information such as
>   usernames, passwords, or cookies sent
>   to another site. Most
>   JavaScript-related security bugs are
>   breaches of either the same origin
>   policy or the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can't save a file on the client side, you won't have the access rights

Comment: How much can we stuff inside a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

you should save a file using a server side language to save locally to your server, you are not allowed to save on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

**If** your target browser has **localStorage**, you can use that to save data on the client side.

[Check quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html#localstorage) for compatibility, which at this point in time is pretty limited.